# How to compute YTD data on amazon-Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Let's say that I have a dataset with a field `Date` and a field `Sales` and that each month, my sales are 5$. I would like to build the following table in quicksight :

```
Date      Sales
Jan 2021      5
Feb 2021     10
Mar 2021     15
...
Dec 2021     60
Jan 2022      5
```

Maybe the [runningSum function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/runningSum-function.html) could be the solution but I can't find the right way to reach the expected result. How please could I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to deal with the runningSum function.

First, create the computed field `qs_year` :

```
extract("YYYY",{Date})
```

Then, our target computed field is :

```
runningSum(sum({Sales}), [truncDate("MM",{Date}) ASC], [{qs_year}])
```